# Access modifiers

Tags: java, class, methods, access-modifiers

I'm new to Java and OOP and I would need some help with understading a few things. Say you have the following class:

```
public class NewClass {
    private long time;

    public NewClass () {
      time = 0;
    }

    public NewClass (long time) {
      this.time = time;
    }

    public long GetAsMs () {
      return time;
    }

    public boolean isGreaterThan(NewClass span) {
      return GetAsMs() > span.GetAsMs();
    }
```

I know that If I make a new instance of this class I will have an object containing the field/variable `time` and associated methods. I don't understand what is the method `isGreaterThan` exactly doing and how do I call it. Aren't these two "variables" that it is comparing always exactly the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They might be different, note the constructor that accepts a parameter:

```
public NewClass (long time) {
      this.time = time;
}
```

If you construct two objects:

```
NewClass xObj = new NewClass(12345678910);
NewClass yObj = new NewClass(12345678919);
```

Now `xObj.isGreaterThan(yObj)` will return `false`. Why? Let's see what's happening there:

`isGreaterThan` is applied on `xObj` object, which has the class member `time` that has the value 12345678910. You're passing `yObj` that has it's own `time`, which has the value 12345678919 - And they are different, `GetAsMs` will return two different results when applied on different objects.

Comment: Can you provide an example with two instances of `NewClass` and with `isGreaterThan` method being called?